# Get page title of view and panel page via url

Tags: views, panels, uri, 7

Is there any way to get page title of view and panel page using url. I tried

```
$normal_path = drupal_get_normal_path($path);
$item = menu_get_item($normal_path);
$title = $item['title'];
```

and it is giving empty title while it is working well for normal node.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

For pannel you can pass the page title in url
let say xyz/page_title
then add content to panel and choose New custom content in the body field your code will somewhat look like

```
<?php
  $title = arg(1);
  drupal_set_title($title);
?>
```

check screenhot for better understanding:[image]

For views its a simple 2 step process
step1: Set the view path to take the title as wildcard
i.e. your view path will be view_path/%
[image]

step2: now change the title field on views to use the title wildcard by changing it to %1 as this is the first argument in the url
[image]

hope it helps you :)

Comment: I missed out to put
,"to use php in the body field you should have php filter module enabled."

Comment: Thank you arpitr. It can be helpful for new panels and views. But I cannot turn on php filter. :-(

Comment: cissharp you don't need php filter turned on for changing title in views.